# Como usar caminho relativo na função fopen?

Tags: php, wordpress

Tenho esse handle que faz leitura de um CSV:

```php
<?php

$handle = fopen("/csv/listalistalevantamentoestoque.csv", "r");

$row = 0;
while ($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) {
    if ($row++ == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $people[] = [
        'nome' => $line[0],
        'site' => $line[1],
        'telefone' => $line[2],
        'idade' => $line[3]
    ];
}

print_r($people);

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Quando rodo o handle ele retorna esse erro dizendo que não encontrou o arquivo. Sendo que este CSV em questão está numa pasta "csv" no mesmo diretório de handle php.

Saída:

```
Warning: fopen(/csv/listalevantamentoestoque.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/folic/wp-content/themes/Avada/woocommerce/get-stock/handle.php on line 3
```

Comment: "no mesmo diretório", mas você apontou para a pasta em relação à raiz do sistema. Usar a barra no início faz com que o caminho seja absoluto a partir da raiz. Se quer uma pasta no mesmo diretório faça `./csv/...` ou o mais indicado `__DIR__ . '/csv/...'`.

Comment: ```php $handle = fopen(__DIR__ . "/csv/listalevantamentoestoque.csv", "r");``` Funcionou! Thank :)